# Manually set Authentication token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, token

I recently updated an app and push to heroku, one of the features updated was changing my session id from the user id to a secure hex. Once pushed i noticed that pervious users could no longer log in. I checked the heroku console and found out that their authentication token was set to nil which is expected i guess. my questions are:

Is there a way to set authentication token for the users prior to update?
Can I write some sort of loop to create this token for users prior to update to prevent this from happening again?

or do i have to just wipe the database and let users sign up again.

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from [Remember Me & Reset Password](http://railscasts.com/episoades/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=comments) comments section.

**TRY IT ON YOUR DEVELOPMENT DATABASE**

I try it some time ago and it work it will update authentication token for all your users if **generate_token** is the method name and **auth_token** is a DB field where you store a token. You can thinker with if statement inside task if you just need to change it for users who don't have a token at the moment.

create file in **lib/tasks/rebuild_token_auth.rake:**

```
namespace :user do
  desc "Rebuild Auth-Tokens"
  task :rebuild_auth_token => :environment do
    User.transaction do
      User.all.each { |u|
        u.generate_token(:auth_token)
        u.save!
      }
    end
  end
end
```

call it like this:

```
rake user:rebuild_auth_token
```

In his example generate_token looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def generate_token(column)
   begin
     self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
   end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
 end
end
```

Comment: Worked 100% you saved me alot here. Thanks alot.